# How to use Matlab to estimate parameters of the autoregressive(AR) model with input-output delay?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, linear-regression

I know there are several functions, such as aryule and arborg, which can estimate coefficients of AR models. But these functions cannot deal with AR models with input-output delay.

I also learned that the newest Matlab includes a function named 'arx' that can estimate AR parameters including the input-output delay. Unfortunately, the current version of Matlab I used is 2013a and I didn't find this 'arx' function inside.

I am wondering if anybody would kindly help me to tackle this issue.

Comment: Well, newest is a relative term... It has almost a decade i guess :)..... It is part of the `System Identification` toolbox. Did you find it? if not, just contact me...

Comment: I am not sure if our company has bought this tool box. If so, I should find this function when I type 'doc arx' in the command window, right?

Comment: yes, as simple as that... :)